# ways to distribute 12 distinct books to 6 kids so that each one gets the same number of books

Tags: combinatorics

I know off the bat that each kid gets two books. Then I do the following, 
$${12 \choose 2}{10 \choose 2}{8 \choose 2}{6 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{2 \choose 2}$$ I was told that I didn't have to divide by $6!$ but I don't understand why. I thought since there are 6 groups of equal sizes I need it to do so to account for over counting. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The children are distinguishable from each other, so you are selecting an ordered collection of pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Bennet's comment above answers your specific question. Here's a different way to do the counting:

Shuffle the books and deal them out, two at a time, to each kid. There are $12!$ permutations of the books, but this overcounts by a factor of $2$ for each child because the pair of books that she gets can come up two ways. So, the number of ways to distribute the books is $\left . {12!}\middle/ \right . {2^6}$, which can easily be seen to be equal to the expression in the question.